# Random timeout on GET request with Axios

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, axios, wordpress-rest-api, gridsome

I have multiple sites buildt with static sites generator (gridsome, vue based).On build, they consume WP REST API data through Axios.

Lately, my build would fail a lot because **Axios requests get randomly timedout**.

[image: Build log Axios]

On the **WP side**, each request made by axios is returning a **200 response**, the body of the response is well formed. Nothing odd.
But Axios will randomly receive nothing...

[image: WP REST API log]

**I don't know where to search** since the requests are returning 200, what could go wrong between the response (being 200) and Axios ?

Additional clues :

- I never have these timeout using postman, or my browser
- The endpoints in WP REST API that timeouts are random
- I use REST API LOG to monitor the states of the requests on WP side
- No matter the timeout configured on axios, it just never get the response

Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks for your time

Comment: You didn't specify the actual error so it can be seen on the image, consider posting all info that doesn't benefit from being an image as text. It's not evident that this is a timeout. This is suggested by the fact that it quickly retries, make sure you don't have a version that mixes them together, https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1543 . Otherwise this not related to Axios but details of your setup, i.e. where is the server and what are other things involved (Nginx, etc). The last time I saw this on SSR build was because a server was crashed and reloaded quickly due to RAM issues.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Axios indeed.
Axios in his 0.19 version returned timeouts where they might be other errors involved.
I updated it to v0.22, that show me another error : some JSON response were truncated and not able to be parsed.
Related issues on github :

- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2590
- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1545

I had to switch from axios to node-fetch.